# Warnings in edmx file when upgrading from 3.5 to 4

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, .net-3.5, migration, edmx

I updated my solution from .NET 3.5 to 4.0, and thanks god, I just had to fix minor things.
But what I don't understand is, the edmx file generated many warnings like this:

```
Error 2005: Mapping Association 'FK_CP_C' is redundant:
Its referential integrity constraint provides sufficient information.
You can safely delete the mapping information for this association.
```

Have you ever encountered this?
Should I do take the risk and delete the associations?
I tried to google it but wasn't able to find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well FYI I made a backup of the project before, removed those associations thoat reported an error, updated the model, and the warnings are gone.

I missed to notice what kind of associations caused the warnings.

Hope this might help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, it was helpful to me.