# What does this .NET Entity Framework warning mean?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have dozens of these warnings in my project and I'd like to clean stuff up.  The warning is:

```
Warning 8   Error 2005: Mapping Association 'TPMDBO_TPM_MODIFIEDVALUES_FK1' is redundant: Its referential integrity constraint provides sufficient information.  You can safely delete the mapping information for this association.    C:\TPM\Entity\TPMEntities.edmx  6267    6277    Entity
```

If I double click on it, it loads some awful designer for the .edmx file which is hard to read or figure out what I can safely remove.  I'd much rather work with the XML directly using the text editor of my choice.

Line 6267 says:

```
  <AssociationSetMapping Name="TPMDBO_TPM_MODIFIEDVALUES_FK1" TypeName="VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Entity.TPMDBO_TPM_MODIFIEDVALUES_FK1" StoreEntitySet="TPM_PROJECTCHANGES">
    <EndProperty Name="TPM_MODIFIEDVALUES">
      <ScalarProperty Name="MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID" ColumnName="MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID" />
    </EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="TPM_PROJECTCHANGES">
      <ScalarProperty Name="PROJECTID" ColumnName="PROJECTID" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="VERSIONID" ColumnName="VERSIONID" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID" ColumnName="MODIFIEDATTRIBUTEID" />
      <ScalarProperty Name="CHANGEID" ColumnName="CHANGEID" />
    </EndProperty>
  </AssociationSetMapping>
```

Does this mean I can remove this `AssociationSetMapping` node from the XML completely?  Thanks!

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186961/warnings-in-edmx-file-when-upgrading-from-3-5-to-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue upgrading from the .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 frameworks.

Re-creating the model from the database fixed the issue.